# can't change view tag or stream name in clearcase explorer in linux

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I am not been able to change any parameters in clearcase GUI? Any suggestions how to fix it. 
I want to give the view tag and stream name as I wanted but it is not allowing me to write or change anything in clearcase explorer.

Answer (score 0):

A ClearCase Explorer is for the view, files and directories.

You cannot change the name of a view, through GUI.
You could follow [the process describe in this IBM technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124390#rename-view) (`rmtag`, `unregister`, moving the view storage, `register`, `mktag`...).
But frankly, you would be better off creating a new one (with the same config spec, which means, for an UCM view, create a new UCM view referring to the same Stream)

A ClearCase *Project* Explorer is for all UCM metadata: pvobs, projects, streams, activity.

You cannot change an UCM name through the GUI (at least in 7.x, the ClearTeam 8.x interface could be more helpful).
But you can rename a stream easily enough through `cleartool rename stream:aStream@\aPVob nameName`.

However, I would then recommend to build a new view pointing on the new Stream (instead of resetting the config spec, with a `cd /path/to/your/view; cleartool chstream --generate`)

Comment: More about renaming UCM objects at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21261006